# How to calculate moving average 7 days of milk production of a each cow, Dates not sorted. Excel

Tags: excel, date, moving-average

The daily milk production of each cow is recorded daily. I would like to cancel out the noise. Therefore I would like to use a moving average of seven days ( 3 days before and 3 days after, including current date production) in Excel.

The data is not ordered according to date therefore offset function cannot be used.

[image: RAW Data]

Additional Information: "Date" is in Column A, Cow No in Column B and  Milk in Column C . Rows are from 1-22.

The expected result would be get get a moving average of milk for 7 days of each cow (  -3 days before <=current date and < days+3 days after current date  from each cow.

Similiar function used  to calculate rolling average of past  year is `=AVERAGEIFS(B2:K2,B1:K1,">"&TODAY()-365,B1:K1,"<"&TODAY())`. A similiar formula could be used.

Problem when using sumproduct formula: No Data for 7 days should be 0 7D Average. However is given 1.79 .[Rolling AVerage with the Sumproduct formula Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3ro0.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use a combination of SUMPRODUCT and AVERAGE functions. Note that this is an array formula, so you need to enter it using Ctrl+Shift+Enter keys:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(AVERAGE(IF(($B$2:$B$22=B2)*($A$2:$A$22>=(A2-3))*($A$2:$A$22<=(A2+3)),$C$2:$C$22)))
```

Result:

[image]

The average for the first three entries (D2:D4) is exactly the same as the value in column C, as there are no other dates provided for the range between 23-29 January. The remaining values (D5:D22) should properly present the 7-day average values.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply :) I have inserted the formula as recommended. However, the 7day average is throughout the column the same. Which mistake am I doing? =SUMPRODUCT(AVERAGE(IF(($B$2:$B$22=B2)*($A$2:$A$22>=(A2-3))*($A$2:$A$22<=(A2+3));$C$2:$C$22)))

Comment: No problem at all @Totti! Can you please confirm if you entered this formula using Ctrl+Shift+Enter keys? This will convert it to an Array formula (i.e. {} brackets will appear around the formula).

Comment: I converted it to an Array formula and it worked. However when Tot. Milk  Unit  is not existent for the 7Days the moving average (7d avg) becomes 1.79, but it should be 0. Should an Iferror formula be added into the array formula ? Thank you :)

Comment: Hmm weird! This should not happen. Do you mind pasting a screenshot of this occurrence and I'll have it checked?

Comment: I have added the tabel to the main question "https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3ro0.png"  under the name  Rolling AVerage with the Sumproduct formula Problem

Comment: @Totti thanks for the screenshot. Unfortunately I could not recreate your output (https://i.imgur.com/TcuzEmI.png). Can you do me a favour and apply filters to columns A & B - check if for No 428, for dates between 28/03/19-9/04/19, there are any values in column C. You can also achieve the same by using `=SUMIFS(C:C,B:B,"428",A:A,">=28/03/2019",A:A,"<=09/04/2019")` formula. One more tip, try avoiding referencing the whole columns (A:A, B:B, C:C) as it significantly slows down the whole file (use A1:A100, A1:A1000 etc. instead, depending on the amount of data you hold).

Comment: Great news! Cheers

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the pretiest solution but it works. We can use countifs in the following way:
1. Create a column that combines Cow no and Date (I called it CowNoDate) with the format CowNo + "-" + date(as number). I put it in column C.
2. Sort list by this new column
3. use the following formula in column E to calculate the running average:

```
=SUMIFS(D:D,C:C,">="&B2&"-"&(A2-3),C:C,"<="&B2&"-"&(A2+3))
```

[image: Sample of the solution]

Comment: There is actually no need to sort but it makes it easier to confirm the running average value.